# How can I speed up the VBA to quickly populate these formulas?

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

```
Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=SUMIF('RMI Current'!C[-6],'RMI Static Compare'!C[-6],'RMI Current'!C[32])"
Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=SUMIF('RMI Previous'!C[-7],'RMI Static Compare'!C[-7],'RMI Previous'!C[31])"
Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("I2:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "ABS(RC[-2])"
Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "RC[-3]-RC[-2]"
Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IFERROR(((RC[-4]-RC[-3])/RC[-3]),""Zero Balance"")"
Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("L2:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(RC[-3]>500000,""Material"",""Immaterial"")"
Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("M2:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(AND(RC[-2]>-0.01,RC[-2]<0.01),""Y"",""N"")"
```

I have over 80,000 rows to accommodate these formula and I need the formulas to stop at the last cell in column A/quickly populate the answers without taking 10 minutes each. Please help!

Comment: Ah! Careful, you didn't always explicitly tell what Sheet to use on some ranges. When you do simply `Cells(x,y)`, this runs on the ActiveSheet.  If you want that to be the cells on "RMI Static Compare" sheet, you need to add `Sheets("RMI Static Compare").` before `.Cells()`, similar how you did before `Range()`.  Same goes for your `Rows.Count`, you want to put a sheet in there too.

Comment: Do you need that the formula in the worksheet? Can you fill the rows with the result? It will be faster to do that.

Comment: The formula is already saved in the first cell of that column, so if it is faster to fill down that would be better...is there a code for that?

Comment: @BruceWayne ....What do you mean?

Comment: Hags, I understand that you need to fill the range G2 to 'down', right?

Comment: @Kellsens I updated my code, I need all the formulas to fill down up until the last cell in column A

Comment: Could you send a sample of the worksheet, containing the formulas?

Comment: How do I do that @Kellsens?

Comment: Take a print of your sheet, containing the data and post

Comment: Hags, I think that BruceWayne code will help you.

Comment: your SUMIFS() has three full column references, In this case it resolves to `SUMIFS(A:A,A:A,AM:AM)`  I think you are missing an `R` in the second criteria. `"=SUMIF('RMI Current'!C[-6],'RMI Static Compare'!RC[-6],'RMI Current'!C[32])"`

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the rest of your code, I suggest adding in a `lastRow` variable, and worksheet variable to save some coding space:

```
Sub t()
Dim lastRow&
Dim rmiWS As Worksheet
Set rmiWS = Sheets("RMI Static Compare")

lastRow = rmiWS.Cells(rmiWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With rmiWS
    .Range("G2:G" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('RMI Current'!C[-6],'RMI Static Compare'!C[-6],'RMI Current'!C[32])"
End With

'The above `With` statement is the exact same as the below line. Notice you can use `.` as a placeholder for whatever follows `With`
' Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("G2:G" & Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Cells(Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = .Range("G2:G" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('RMI Current'!C[-6],'RMI Static Compare'!C[-6],'RMI Current'!C[32])"

End Sub
```

Notice the `.` before `Range()`, which effectively "attached" whatever follows `With` to that statement.  This should help you.

Also, from your Formula, you want to use `R1C1` format.

Now the issue is, does the `lastRow`do what you want?

Edit: Woah, the original question has changed since this answer...but the theory still applies to all of your formulas.

Basically, this:
`Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=SUMIF('RMI Current'!C[-6],'RMI Static Compare'!C[-6],'RMI Current'!C[32])"
Sheets`

needs to be either:

```
Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Range("G2:G" & Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Cells(Sheets("RMI Static Compare").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('RMI Current'!C[-6],'RMI Static Compare'!C[-6],'RMI Current'!C[32])"
```

or

```
With Sheets("RMI Static Compare")
    .Range("G2:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('RMI Current'!C[-6],'RMI Static Compare'!C[-6],'RMI Current'!C[32])"
End with
```

Edit2: To put your formula in a range, with it automatically updating so you don't have to drag, do this:

```
With Sheets("RMI Static Compare")
   .Range("G2:G2").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF('RMI Current'!C[-6],'RMI Static Compare'!C[-6],'RMI Current'!C[32])"
End With
```

You just need to set a range to a cell, then resize the row count - 1

Editx:  Also, add these lines to the top of your Sub, and the others at the bottom:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

then at the bottom

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: What would I do to accommodate the formulas I have above?

Comment: And its not automatically updating the formulas, I have to go back in the cell and drag the formula down for them to update...

Comment: @Hags - I'm going to let you attempt this first.  Look over my post, and see if you can understand what I did.  Then, attempt this on your own, and post your code into your OP if you run into issues.  It's pretty straightforward (assuming of course your formulas work, and there are no other issues).

Comment: @Hags - Ah, I think I know why you are having to drag down... I'll edit my post

Comment: That works but the processors run so slow, is there any way to speed up the process?

Comment: Again, I don't know what all of your code is, but check my edit

Comment: FYI there is no benefit to turning off calculation if you assign the formula to entire ranges at once - they have to calculate as you do it. It only helps if you populate the first row and then use `FillDown`.